# tornado websocket execution order issue

Tags: websocket

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
        self.sk_obj = None

    @property
    def ws_db(self):
        # ws_model = WsModel()
        return self.application.ws_db

    @property
    def ws_redis(self):
        # redis = WsRedis()
        return self.application.ws_redis

    async def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sn = self.get_argument('sn', None)
        bt_mac = self.get_argument("bt_mac", None)
        sk_obj = await self.ws_db.get_secretkey_obj(sn, bt_mac)
        if sk_obj is None:
            logger.error(f'{sn}_{bt_mac} Not Match')
            self.close()
            return
        else:
            self.sk_obj = sk_obj

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if self.sk_obj is None:
            logger.error("SKOBJ IS NONE")
            await self.open()
        message = common.check_message(message, self.sk_obj.sn)
```

The on_message method is executed before the open method is finished, I think the on_message method is executed after the open method is finished, otherwise there will be an error getting sk_obj.sn

Comment: The on_message method is executed before the open method is finished，how to avoid